# Why is my php page downloading in google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Please help with a problem!
My PHP script doesn't execute, it downloaded in Google AppEngine.
How solve this problem?

app.yaml:

```
application: web-sites-testing    
version: 1    
runtime: php    
api_version: 1    
threadsafe: yes

handlers:    
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1    
- url: /main.php
  script: main.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change order of the url handler in your app.yaml.According to me it should be like as below:

handlers:
-url: /main.php
  script: main.php

-url: /(.+.php)$
  script: \1

It should work according to my understanding. As previously the /main.php URL pass the regular expression (/(.+.php)$) handler so it try to run the script \1 (as there is no script is defined). When you change the order, the main.php URL handler comes first so it will handled by the main.php script.

Comment: No, it still downloading.

Comment: Is this your complete app.yaml file? Do you have any static file handlers (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) that causes the "download".

Answer (score 0):

I added this as first handler:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

So now my app.yaml looking like this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1    

- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

And php files executed as expected